# How I can re-logging to my website with cookie when i reopen the browser?

Tags: php, authentication, session, logging, cookies

Here is my login script:

```
     <?php
if (isset($_POST["email"]) AND isset($_POST["pass"])) {
  $email=trim($_POST["email"]);
  $pass=trim($_POST["pass"]);

  require_once 'dbh.php';
  require_once 'functions.php';

  if (emptyInputLogin($email, $pass) !== false) {
    header ("location: login_page.php?error=emptyinput");
    exit();
  }

  loginUser($conn, $email, $pass);
}
else {
  header("location: login_page.php");
  exit();
}
?>
```

And here is the loginUser function.
When user is recognised it's create a new session and set a cookie with the session id:

```
function loginUser($conn, $email, $pass){
  $emailExists = emailExists($conn, $email);

  if ($emailExists === false) {
    header("location: login_page.php?error=emailnotexists");
    exit();
  }

  $pwdHashed = $emailExists["usersPwd"];
  $checkPass = password_verify($pass, $pwdHashed);

  if ($checkPass === false) {
    header("location: login_page.php?error=wrongpass");
    exit();
  }
  else if ($checkPass === true) {
    session_start();
    $_SESSION["userEmail"] = $emailExists["usersEmail"];
    setcookie("sessionID", session_id(), time()+3600); //expire in 1 hour

    header("location: index.php");
  }
}
```

Finally my php code in example index page. The session id show are the same.

```
  <?php
  echo "Session ID: " . session_id() . "<br />Cookie [sessionid]: ". $_COOKIE["sessionID"];
  ?>
```

I think that saving the username of the logged in user in the cookie in the client and then considering that logged in user in a new session is unsafe, so I thought of saving the remote session id locally. But then I don't know how I can access the data (user, name, surname) of the user connected to that session!
I know my code is very shallow .. How can I implement re-login?

Comment: emailExists returns the row of the user in database if there is one user, else return false